# Setting a maximum and minimum value for text box

Tags: php, javascript

I own a canvas website and want my customers to be able to enter a custom length of the canvas within a set range.

Say the range for the product is:

- Minimum: 10 cm
- Maximum: 200 cm

Then in the text box they can enter any number between that range, but if they enter "215" then it should automatically go down to "200". Likewise if they enter "7" then it should automatically go up to "10"

Comment: Input text fields have a `maxlength` attribute, but there's no minlength. You can put some javascript in there to detect insufficient data, as long as you do the same check server-side afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('textBoxID').onchange = function(){
      if(this.value > 200){
           this.value = 200;
      }
      if(this.value < 10){
           this.value = 10;
      }
}
```

Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qwFN6/

Comment: although this will work, onchange is fired along with blur so the user experience might not be the greatest

Comment: @locrizak so use `onkeyup` instead -- although that would ruin things when the 1st number a user enters is **always** below 10

Comment: @Neal, you should add to also use `$('#textBoxID').numeric()` to prevent non-numeric characters.

Comment: @Justin -- where did libraries come into the picture? the question asked about plain javascript...

Comment: @Justin -- you can add that type of validation as well with plain js. just its more work ^_^

Comment: In case anyone wants to, the following should work:  http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_158.html

Comment: Hi Neal, thank you for your answer but for some reason I can't get it to work. I'm quite the rookie when it comes to programming, but I assumed it was simply just a case of:

Comment: @Michael -- can you post that part of your code in jsfiddle? (also do you have any js errors on the page at all?)

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter. I thought I should just put the javascript code in <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> brackets and then pace the normal html underneath, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Neal, to test it, I simply just created a blank page with your code - first the javascript code in script-brackets and then the html-box. But no success.

Comment: @Michael, you need to place this script **after** the html that it will be affecting

Comment: @Michael either do what i said in the previous comment **or** put the code into a `window.onload` function as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qwFN6/show/ (look in the head script tag)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text"
    onchange="this.value = (this.value > 215) ? 215 : ((this.value < 10) ? 10 : this.value);">
```

Comment: this seems like a more confusing way of doing what I did in my answer -- also inline js is not always the best way to go

Comment: @Neal, your suggestion is definitely better. I just wanted to show the inline way.

Answer (score 0):

Find below jQuery based code

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <style>
    #customForm input.error{
        background: #f8dbdb;
        border-color: #e77776;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //global vars
        var form = $("#customForm");    
        var canvas = $("#canvasID");
        var canvasInfo= $("#canvasInfo");
        //On blur   
        canvas.blur(validateCanvas);    

        //On Submitting
        form.submit(function(){
            if(validateCanvas())
                return true
            else
                return false;
        });

        function validateCanvas(){
            //if it's NOT valid
        if(canvas.val()< 10 || canvas.val()>200){
            if(canvas.val()< 10) {
                canvas.val('10');
            }
            if(canvas.val()>200) {
                canvas.val('200');
            }
                canvas.addClass("error");
                canvasInfo.text("We want canvas Minimum: 10 cm and Maximum: 200 cm");           
                return false;
            }
            //if it's valid
            else{       
                canvas.removeClass("error");
                canvasInfo.text("");
                return true;
            }
        }   
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: also i realize  that this has **nothing** to do with the OP's question

Comment: Good point Neal thanks, It was my mistake I had updated wrong content. But now I have updated my script